# setting up a mysql database to record tasks

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time, task

I am trying to setup a MySQL database using PHPMyAdmin. Before I get long into it I want advice on setting it up and querying it. I set the table like this.

```
id: primary ket
time_in: date
time_out: date
task: varchar (128)
business: varchar (128)
```

All I need it to do is to keep track of how much time spent on each task and for what business. Is this good way of doing it or is there a better way?

If this is correct then I am trying to figure out how to query the time. This is what I have come up with as a query, but it far from what I want.

```
SELECT `Task`,`Business`, (SELECT `Time-Out` - `Time-In`) as `total time` FROM `Sheet`
```

Is there a way to convert total time into a more readable format?

Comment: You probably want to use datetime instead of date.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time) and TIME_TO_SEC(time) to convert the difference to a total number of seconds.  You can then convert the seconds mathematically to whatever format you want.

So for the time of each task:

```
 select ID
       ,task
       ,business
       ,time_to_sec(timediff(time_out, time_in)) as duration
 from sheet
```

To aggregate by task and business:

```
 select task
       ,business
       ,sum(time_to_sec(timediff(time_out,time_in))) as total_time
 from sheet
 group by task
         ,business
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful.

Comment: @Husbandman, you should generally up-vote those answers which are helpful and accept an answer if it is your preferred solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're tracking time in days, I'd recommend using `TIME` or `DATETIME` for the `time_in` and `time_out` columns.

Personally, I'd probably make `time_out` nullable, to allow tracking current activity (something I've started, but not yet finished).

There's no need to use a sub-select for subtracting the timestamps, you can subtract those two columns inline as well (just drop the `SELECT` keyword there). For formatting, you could use the `TIMEDIFF` function:

```
SELECT '12:00:00' - '10:45:00';
-> 2

SELECT TIMEDIFF('12:00:00', '10:45:00');
-> '01:15:00'
```

That would make your query:

```
SELECT `Task`, `Business`, TIMEDIFF(`Time-Out`, `Time-In`) as `total time` FROM `Sheet`
```

If you *do* make `time_out` (or `Time-Out`) nullable, you'll need to take that into account in your query:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NULL, '10:45:00');
-> NULL
```

So ongoing tasks would give a `total time` of NULL. If you want to know how long you've been working already, you can wrap it in an `IFNULL` function and get the current time in that case:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(`Time-Out`, NOW()), `Time-In`);
-> '01:15:00' if `Time-Out` is 12:00:00 and `Time-In` is 10:45:00
-> '02:05:13' if `Time-Out` is NULL and it's currently 12:50:13 (server time)
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful.